# C# Target-Typed Conditional Expression

Tags: c#

Looking at the documentation for [Target-Typed Conditional Expression in C# 9](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-conditional-expression).

A reference is made to *ambiguity* in the documentation for the following scenario after the introduction of this feature, but it still appears to call `M(long, long)` every time. i.e. no ambiguity?

> ```
> M(b ? 1 : 2, 1); // calls M(long, long) without this feature; ambiguous with this feature.
>
> static void M(short i, short ii) => Console.WriteLine("short");
> static void M(long i, long ii) => Console.WriteLine("long");
> ```

Compiles to:

```
public static void Main()
{
    M(1L, 1L);
}

private static void M(short i, short ii) { Console.WriteLine("short, short"); }
private static void M(long i, long ii) { Console.WriteLine("long, long");
```

Comment: I tried with .net 5/6/7 - all showed same results of compiling fine (and calling `M(long, long)`.

Comment: If `b` is declared as constant, say `const bool b = true;`, both overloads are possible, and the most specific one `M(short, short)` is picked by overload resolution.

Comment: This is complicated. If I keep `const bool b = true;`, then `M(b ? 5 : 9876543, 1);` goes to short, but `M(b ? 5 : 987654321098, 1);` goes to long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ambiguity in the case you describe it entirely internal. It is not exposed to the user.

For clarity, this is the case:

```
static void Main()
{
    M(1, 2); // Case A
    M(true ? 1 : 2, 3); // Case B
    bool b = true;
    M(b ? 1 : 2, 3);  // Case C
}
static void M(short a, short b) => Console.WriteLine($"{a} {b} {a.GetType()}");
static void M(long a, long b) => Console.WriteLine($"{a} {b} {a.GetType()}");
```

Case A and B can be evaluated by the builder (Case B generates the IL code `M(1, 3);` - the conditional is not even presented to the runtime), so both resolve to the `short` implementation, but case C is where the ambiguity lies.

When the runtime needs to decide which version to call, it does a first pass and determines that both expressions resolve to different types. `b ? 1 : 2` resolves to an `int` when considered on its own, and `3` also resolves to an `int`, but in the context of this problem, the pattern matcher needs to either resolve both to `short` or `long`.

The pattern matcher doesn't want to fully evaluate `b ? 1 : 2`, (or even determine the possible types - remember that this could be an expensive and nested case) but it has been predetermined to be of type `int`. `3` can be expressed as `short` to match the first case, but `int` can't be implicitly cast to `short`, only to `long`, so it makes that first step.

Therefore we have a call to `M` of type `M(long, short)`, which is **ambiguous**. This can be solved by either:

1. Implicitly casting the second argument `3` to a `long`
2. Evaluating the first parameter `b ? 1 : 2` to see if it can be expressed as a short

When presented with these options, the runtime will always do the first one if that option exists. From the [proposal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-conditional-expression) you posted, this is 'clarified' by:

[The updated terminology](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-conditional-expression#better-conversion-from-expression) referenced (the new proposal is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/draft-v7/standard/expressions.md#12644-better-conversion-from-expression)), `C1` in this case is option 1 in that list above (not a conditional expression conversion - i.e. implicit), and `C2` is option 2 (IS a conditional expression conversion), so `C1` is considered 'Better'.

The last line in the link is what clarified things for me:

> Therefore we treat the conditional expression conversion as a last resort in a cast, to preserve existing behavior.

Basically, it guesses what the best fit will be, and in `b ? 1 : 2`, both outcomes resolve to `int`, so when it comes to deciding which method to call, the **last** thing it will do is evaluate that conditional to figure out that a `short` works better, and both `int` and `short` are implicitly convertible to `long`

Of course, this can be forced with `M((short)(b ? 1 : 2), 3);`, but where's the fun in that?

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The crux here is the ternary operator. In this case, it will upcast to [Int32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32) (`int`):

```cs
Console.WriteLine((b ? 1 : 2).GetType().Name);
```

Given the rules of overloading, the only valid overload available of `M` is `M(long, long)`

If you explicitly type the numbers, then the ternary will resolve to [Int16](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int16) (`short`):

```cs
const short one = 1;
const short two = 2;
        
Console.WriteLine((b ? one : two).GetType().Name);
```

In this case, the closest overload of `M` is `M(short, short)`

Another way:

```cs
Console.WriteLine((b ? (short)1 : (short)2).GetType().Name);
```

Comment: I am still confused as to what is meant by *ambiguity* in their documentation. In your answer, there is none and will always match `M(long, long)` ?